# Sitecore ApplicationCache

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore8

Recently, I have installed Sitecore 8.0.

The problem is slowness. Whenever I reload page(s) in Edit Mode, it is too slow.
Below is Console in Development tool in Chrome and most final message is "ApplicationCache is not declared"

[image]

It seems like I need to declare ApplicationCache in Sitecore. How can I do??

**=== Updated ===**
By enabling Application Cache, I could see caching is correctly working. However, after caching loads, SPEAK still calls all SPEAK tool ribbons.

Why????????????? how can I make Sitecore stop loading these???

Comment: There is another way to resolve this. I updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**===== Update ====**

In another way, you can disable SPEAK UI extender.
Go to `/website/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.MvcExperienceEditor.config` file and Enable `SheerUI Ribbon` and disable `SPEAK UI Ribbon`.

```
<!-- The SheerUI-based Experience Editor ribbon.  -->

<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageEditorExtender, Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor"></processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPreviewExtender, Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor"></processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderDebugExtender, Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor"></processor>


<!-- The SPEAK-based Experience Editor ribbon
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.SpeakRibbon.RenderPageEditorSpeakExtender, Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor"></processor>
-->
```

Even you disable SPEAK-based ribbon, there would be no UI changes.

Answer (score 1):

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/the_editing_tools/improve_the_performance_of_the_experience_editor_ribbon

The web application cache is disabled by default. To enable it:

Add the following string

```
manifest="/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Html5AppCache.ashx"
```

to the HTML tag inside the current layout of the item or page, for example, the `\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Layouts\Layouts\SpeakLayout.cshtml` base layout file.

Move to "\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Layouts\Layouts\SpeakLayout.cshtml" then, update like:

```
<html data-sc-app manifest="/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Html5AppCache.ashx">
```